# Is there a way to use the filter function where the range is determined by the contents of another cell?

Tags: google-sheets, filter

In my spread sheet the rows are names of employees and the columns are names of departments. The data are "X"s denoting that an employee has been trained in that department. I am looking for a way to choose a department from a drop-down menu and have it list the names of all employees trained in that department.

I have tried a formula combining INDEX and MATCH trying to find the nth instance but I keep getting cells with errors or bad data (missing or added names). So far the best I have been able to do is a filter function for each department and then an INDEX/MATCH formula with ISERROR (for cleanliness) dragged down for hundreds of rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=FILTER(A2:A,"X"=XLOOKUP(H2,B1:F1,B2:F,,0))
```

where

A2:A is the range where the names are

B1:F1 are the headers / department names

B2:F is the body of your table where all the Xs will be

and finally H2 is the cell of the dropdown which takes values from B1:F1

[Here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16TSTeOG8ALwWMZZ3ETeWMRenxXqnlN478uNRH1q1wPo/edit?usp=share_link) is a sample sheet.

Edit: Since we use a dropdown to choose the values, the final parameter of XLOOKUP is unnecessary, so the formula could be updated as

```
=FILTER(A2:A,"X"=XLOOKUP(H2,B1:F1,B2:F))
```